# How to test if IFS is unset in ksh93?

Tags: variable, ksh

It seems easy to test if a variable is unset. I know of three ways at least:

```
#!/bin/ksh
unset var
[ "$#" -gt 0 ]               && var=$1
[ "${var+set}" != "${var}" ] && echo set1 || echo unset1
[ "${var+set}" ]             && echo set2 || echo unset2
[[ -v var ]]                 && echo set3 || echo unset3
```

execute it:

```
$ ./script
unset1
unset2
unset3
```

also try with `./script ''` and `./script 'value'`.

but, just change the variable name to `IFS` and all three tests will fail:

```
#!/bin/ksh
unset IFS
[ "$#" -gt 0 ]               && IFS=$1
[ "${IFS+set}" != "${IFS}" ] && echo set1 || echo unset1
[ "${IFS+set}" ]             && echo set2 || echo unset2
[[ -v IFS ]]                 && echo set3 || echo unset3
```

Is there a way to actually test if `IFS` is unset in ksh93 ?

Comment: I thought about `if [[ "$IFS"a = a ]]` but it wouldn't unambiguously say if `IFS` is unset or just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  One way (maybe not the easiest, but it does work) is to check the list of all variables whether it contains the variable:

```
if [[ `set | grep ^IFS= | wc -l` == 0 ]]; then
    echo "IFS variable is unset (not declared)"
fi
```

Alternatively, without `wc` (thanks to @Kusalananda, see his note below):

```
if set | ! grep -q ^IFS= ; then
    echo "IFS variable is unset (not declared)"
fi
```

Comment: The variable IFS is not exported, so, no, `env` wont list it, but `set` does. So, maybe we can do this test: `[[ $(set | grep 'IFS=') ]] && echo set || echo unset`. But that seems ugly.

Comment: @Isaac Yes, sorry, corrected my reply. Please let me know if it works for you now. It is not the most elegant way but if it works I usually do not see a problem using grep and wc instead of built-in functions.

Comment: Why the `egrep`? The regular expression uses no extended features. Also, `if set | grep -q '^IFS='; then echo 'IFS is set'; else echo 'IFS is unset'; fi` would be less messy.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I will add it as an alternative. Also, reducing it some more one can remove the '' around the string.

Comment: No need for the command substitution... Use the exit status of `grep -q`. That was kinda my point. Put a `!` in front of `grep` to negate its exit status if you want to test for a non-match.

Comment: @Kusalananda OK, now even more minimised... hope you can live with this one. As you can tell, korn is not my first choice of shell...

Comment: No worries. Nothing in your answer is specific to `ksh93`. It would work in any `sh`-like shell.